# Library imported manually but it's dependencies aren't available ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a javascript library *"c-liberator"* that I need to use in my Ember application I have imported it manually as it's not a npm or bower package but its dependencies aren't being included, when I try to use one of its functions I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: md5 is not a function
```

I tried importing the exact md5 module that *"c-liberator"* uses and If I use it in a function in application.js it works fine so the md5 module works fine it's just that *"c-liberator"* is not using it.

The code below runs fine in application.js but throws the uncaught type error in *"c-liberator"*

```
var creds = md5('username' + ':' + 'pass');
```

I have also tried installing the md5 library one at a time with bower and npm  and confirmed it was referenced by bower.json and package.json, this didn't change anything.

The minified md5 library is in c-liberator/libmd5.min.js and I have also tried putting into ember-cli-build.js which didn't work either

```
app.import('vendor/c-liberator/c-liberator.js', {
    amdModule: 'clib'
  });
  app.import('vendor/c-liberator/lib/md5.min.js', {
    amdModule: 'md5'
  });
```

**Edit**
Here is that code that I'm running 'creds' works fine but when the same code is executed by Clib.login() it throws that error

```
cLiberate: function() {
    var creds = md5('username' + ':' + 'pass');
    alert(creds);
    var C;
    Clib.login('testuser@email.co.nz', 'notarealpassword', '1000000', function(userAgent) {
      C = userAgent;
      console.log('Login successful');
    }, function(data, status) {
      alert('Login error');
    });
  }.on('init'),
```

Any help would be really appericated.

Thanks
Hamish

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with code I had already tried

```
app.import('vendor/c-liberator/lib/md5.min.js', {
    amdModule: 'md5'
  });
```

No clue why it didn't work before